# Modelo-relacional no firebird com C#

Tags: c#, sql, firebird, chave-estrangeira

Desenvolvendo um pequeno projeto em C# com  Visual Studio, banco firebird e ibexpert. Com as tabelas SEM RELACIONAMENTO consigo executar tudo direitinho. Mas preciso de relacionar `CLIENTE` 1:N com `BONUS` E `SAIDA`.
Não estou conseguindo desenvolver o seguinte raciocínio:

Tenho uma tabela chamada: `CLIENTE` com `ID_CLIENTE` (Chave primária), `ID_BONUS` (Chave ESTRANGEIRA),`ID_SAIDA` (Chave ESTRANGEIRA), `NOME` e `Data`.

Tabela `BONUS` com `ID_BONUS` (Chave primaria), `data` , hora1`, hora2`, `total`.
Tabela `SAIDA` com `ID_SAIDA` (Chave Estrangeira), `data` , `hora1`, `hora2`, `total`.

Um Form1 para `CLIENTE` com DATAGRID e outro Form2 para `BONUS` E `SAIDA` (2 DATAGRID).

Devo colocar textbox para as chaves estrangeiras em `CLIENTE`?
E como posso chamar o Form2, é pela chave primaria, do `BONUS` e `SAIDA`?

Meu codigo sem relacionamento: 1 botão pesquisar no Form1 e um botão que acessa o Form2.

```c#
string mSQL = "Select * from CLIENTE Where ID_CLIENTE = " + id;
```

Comment: Acho que a tag [tag:modelo-relacional] se encaixaria melhor no lugar de [tag:chave-estrangeira].

Answer (score 6):

Creio que você trocou as bolas, as chaves estrangeiras sempre ficam do lado N.

Suas tabelas ficariam mais ou menos assim:

---

tabela cliente

- id_cliente (chave primaria)
- nome
- data

tabela bonus

- id_bonus (chave estrangeira, referencia id_cliente)
- data
- hora1
- hora2
- total

tabela saida

- id_saida (chave estrangeira, referencia id_cliente)
- data
- hora1
- hora2
- total

---

Dependendo da sua regra de negócio, você pode até pedir ao usuário para colocar a chave estrangeira, mas isso não é recomendável, pois abre muitas brechas para falhas. O ideal é que quando você for cadastrar um novo bônus/saída, faça um `select` da chave primária do usuário a partir dos dados que você já possui sobre o mesmo na aplicação.

Dica: não concatene uma variável com uma *query*, use sempre comandos parametrizados.

Comment: Olá Patrick.Há muito não via Sql e este projeto pede. Obrigada pela dica sobre as chaves estrangeiras. Já me deu uma luz.

Comment: @Cacau, é possível utilizar um recurso do FB para controlar os id's, chama-se sequence(que seria o mesmo que o auto increment do mysql). Uma forma possível de implementar está neste link http://www.devmedia.com.br/auto-incremento-firebird/17924 Fica como sugestão.

Comment: link especificamente sobre sequences: http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-ddl-sequence.html

Comment: id_bonus e id_saida deveriam ser chaves primárias locais. Cada uma dessas tabelas deveriam ter uma id_cliente que seria a chave estrangeira referenciando o id_cliente da tabala cliente.

Comment: @EMBarbosa, questão de nomenclatura, isso é apenas um exemplo.

Comment: Verdade. Mas confunde quem está iniciando ou não tem costume de trabalhar com isso.